# Getting Relationship properties using spring data neo4j node repository

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

If we have a Company Node like this which is linked to another Node (Location) using OWNS relationship.

```
@NodeEntity ("Company")
public class Company {
@Id
@Property
private String companyId;

@Property
private String partyId;

@Relationship (type = "OWNS", direction = Relationship . OUTGOING )
private Set<Location> ownedLocations;
}
```

OWNS relationship

```
@RelationshipEntity (type = "OWNS")
public class Owns {
@Property
private String ownsProperty;
@StartNode
private Company company;
@EndNode
private Location location;
}
```

Here is the Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Company, String> {
@Query ("match (c:Company)-[x:OWNS]-(y) where c.partyId = $0 return c,x,y")
Stream<Company> getCompaniesWithRelationsByPartyId(final String partyId);
}
```

So when i run this query i am getting only Company and Location entities but no OWNS ownsProperty. How to get relationship properties using above repository?

NOTE: I don't want to use @QueryResult

enter code here

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `Owns` relationship entity as the type for the relationship in the `Company` like this

```
@Relationship (type = "OWNS", direction = Relationship . OUTGOING )
private Set<Owns> ownedLocations;
```

Comment: By adding both linked domain entities and relationship, i am getting only relationship but not linked domain entities. Any idea why?

Comment: There is no need for having both mapped. You can access the Location through the OWN relationship. The ambiguous mapping does not work because one will get (randomly) picked up as the target.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are suggesting to use only relationship entities and get end nodes from the relationships, as it would be similar to related entities?

Comment: For your case with relationships with properties, yes. Getting to the end node via a relationship entity is intended behavior.